# Time Series Plot Matrix

Tags: r, ggplot2, timeserieschart, ggfortify

I have a question concerting R:
I was trying to plot a set of daily time series commodity data in R with the package `ggplot2` and `ggfortify` into a matrix. I am trying to have standardized values on each y axis and the dates 1/1/2007, 1/1/2008... on the x axis. 
The visual concept should look like this:

[image]

Does anyone know how that works ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You need to make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) with adequate sample data to reproduce the situation.

Comment: Check out `autoplot.zoo` in the `zoo` package for some examples. (Also the replication code for the JSS paper you mention is available along with the nanuscript.)

Answer (score 4):

The `zoo` package provides support for time series with flexible time indexes, e.g., including `Date`. The package also brings a `fortify()` method that can be leveraged for `ggplot2` graphics. A convenience method for `autoplot()` is also provided, see `?autoplot.zoo` for a selection of worked examples with different layouts.

For an example with 18 time series with `Date` index in a 3 x 6 layout, I use a subset of the data set `FXRatesCHF` from package `fxregime`. This provides exchange rates for different currencies with respect to the Swiss Franc (CHF).

```
library("zoo")
data("FXRatesCHF", package = "fxregime")
FX <- window(FXRatesCHF[, c(1:4, 6:19)], start = as.Date("2000-01-01"))
```

Then `ggplot()` can be applied to the output of the `fortify()` method:

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(aes(x = Index, y = Value), data = fortify(FX, melt = TRUE)) +
  geom_line(color = "darkred") +
  xlab("Time") + ylab("FX") +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~ Series, scales = "free_y", ncol = 6)
```

[image: FX ggplot2]

The same kind of layout can also be easily created with base graphics. Only the panel titles are on the y-axis rather than in a gray-shaded main title:

```
plot(FX, col = "darkred", xlab = "Time", nc = 6,
  panel = function(...) { grid(col = "lightgray"); lines(...) })
```

[image: FX base graphics]

Finally, a `lattice` version can be created by

```
library("lattice")
trellis.par.set(theme = standard.theme(color = FALSE))
xyplot(FX, col = "darkred", xlab = "Time", layout = c(6, 3),
  panel = function(...) { panel.grid(col = "lightgray"); panel.lines(...) })
```

[image: FX lattice]

Comment: I have tried the following solution an dit worked very well: '# Standardize the data
data_std <- data
for (i in 2:26)
{data_std[,i] <- (data_std[,i] - mean(data_std[,i])) / sd(data_std[,i])}

# Create a variable that contains the date in a view that R can deal with:
date <- as.Date(data$time, format="%m/%d/%Y")
data_std$time <- date

# Create the new dataframe "datalili"
newdata_wheat <- data_std[,1:2]
names(newdata_wheat)[2]<-paste("price")
newdata_wheat["commodity"] <- "wheat"
datalili <- newdata_wheat'

Comment: I would still recommend to use a proper time series object (e.g., `zoo` as in my example) because there are dedicated plotting facilities for this. And the `for()` loop for scaling the data is also unnecessarily clumsily. If you want to scale the data in my example, simply include `FX <- scale(FX)` prior to plotting.